# Registering the first administrator user

Tags: strapi

**System Information**

- Strapi V4.5.6
- Windows 10
- SQlite
- Node v16.17.0
- NPM 8.15.0
- Yarn 1.22.19

I just created a new project with strapi, following the quick start guide. However, I can’t manage to create the first administrator user from the admin registration page. I get a 400 (Bad Request) when I press on the "Let’s start" button. I’ve provided all the information necessary and even a valid email. Has anyone else encountered this?

I read the official guide, but there was no relevant information to this issue.

Comment: Have you read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333883/strapi-returns-error-code-400-on-user-registration)? It may be an email issue.

Comment: Yes, I did read it, but it seemed like they at least already had access to the admin dashboard, which I can't at the moment, as I am attempting to register for the first time.

Comment: Judging by the lack of response here, It looks like the best course may be to raise an issue on their Github rather than on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Martin good point, I'll do that.